# Should I care about manufacturer-specific GPT partition type for boot partition?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, gpt

Laptop **Lenovo** g710 (UEFI) with preinstalled Windows. Going to format disk (**GPT**) to **install linux**.

```
EFI System partition GUID (common) - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
Lenovo boot partition GUID         - BFBFAFE7-A34F-448A-9A5B-6213EB736C22
```

Will there be any difference if I choose one over another? What is the reason for manufacturers to have specific type (how is this GUID used)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the official EFI System Partition (ESP) type code (C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B; EF00 in `gdisk`; or a "boot flag" set in `parted`, GParted, and other libparted-based tools).

Manufacturers sometimes create their own partition type codes for various reasons. One I've heard from a reliable source is that some Linux distributions' installation programs used to have bugs that caused them to wipe out ESPs, so creating their own type codes would protect the boot loaders on those partitions from misbehaving Linux installers. Such bugs have long since been excised from mainstream Linux distributions. For instance, the [Ubuntu bug for this problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/partman-efi/+bug/769669) was closed out prior to the release of Ubuntu 12.04 (in 2012, 3.5 years ago).

If you know what you're doing and use recent software, you should be able to share a single ESP using the standard partition type code without problems. That said, it's wise to keep a backup of your ESP, since it really is critically important. A file-level backup (just copying files to a USB flash drive, or using `zip`, `tar`, or some similar file-level tool) should be sufficient.

Using a manufacturer-specific (or any other) type code will *probably* work, but there's a chance that you'll run into problems with utilities that look for the ESP using the standard ESP type code. This is especially true if you use the non-standard code exclusively and don't have a regular ESP.